WebdriverIO: Error: "Snapshot service is not initialized"
I'm trying to initialize a new WebdriverIO (wdio@v9) project, with the configuration below.
After this, when running npm run wdio, I get expect(...).toMatchElementSnapshot is not a function. When I replace this with the function toMatchSnapshot, I get the message: Error: Snapshot service is not initialized. What should I do? Could you guys please point me somewhere where I can find more information about this? I have scoured the web, but I didn't manage to find anything related to it. Thank you in advance.
Setup: node v20.17.0 (LTS), npm 10.8.2 (Linux, OpenSuSE x86-64)
Project setup: npm init wdio@latest ./wdio-test
Options:

E2E testing
Local machine
Web testing in the browser
Chrome browser only
Testing framework: Jasmine only
Typescript
Auto-gen some test files: yes
Default tests location
Page objects: no
Test reporter: jUnit
Extra plugins: no
Visual testing: yes
Extra services: visual
NPM install: yes

package.json:
{
  "name": "wdio-test",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^5.1.4",
    "@wdio/cli": "^9.0.7",
    "@wdio/jasmine-framework": "^9.0.7",
    "@wdio/junit-reporter": "^9.0.4",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^9.0.7",
    "@wdio/visual-service": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "wdio": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.ts"
  }
}

wdio.conf.ts: default
